# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable (python)

Tags: python, object, matrix, int, multiplication

I'm having problems making a matrix multiplication algorithm in python3.

This is the code:

```
def matrixMult(m1, m2):
    result = [[0 for x in range(len(m1))] for x in range(len(m2[0]))]
    # Iterate through rows of m1.
    for i in range(len(m1)):
        # Iterate through columns of m2.
        for j in range(len(m2[0])):
            # Iterate through rows of m2.
            for k in range(len(m2)):
                result[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]   # error occurs here.

    return result
```

Trying to call it on two random matrices like so:

```
m = [3, 4, 2]
n = [[13, 9, 7, 15], [8, 7, 4, 6], [6, 4, 0, 3]]
r = matrixMult(m, n)
```

This results in the `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` message.

I added a `print(type())` for both the matrices declared above and they are of class `'list'`. Did the same for the classes used in the function prototype, class `'list'`. Hell, everything is of type `'list'`. I don't know what the `int object` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating `m1` as a nested list of integers:

```
result[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]
#               ^^^^^^^^
```

It is not; it is merely a simple list of integers. `m1[i]` then is an integer object and you cannot index integers:

```
>>> [3, 4, 2][0]
3
>>> [3, 4, 2][0][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

You probably want to use *just* `i` as the index:

```
result[i][j] += m1[i] * m2[k][j]
```

or pass in two-dimensional arrays only (so pass in `[[3], [4], [2]]` rather than `[3, 4, 2]`).

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. How would you suggest I deal with one dimensional matrices?

Comment: @tudorv: well, how *do* you multiply a one-dimensional array with a 2-dimensional array normally? You could pass in a two-dimensional array with just one column each, or you need to adjust your multiplication code to work with one-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following index operation

```
m1[i][k]
```

But `m1` was passed in as

```
m = [3, 4, 2]
```

It only has 1 dimension to index from, not 2.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the help. How would you suggest I deal with one dimensional matrices?